# Connect 3D points with lines/bars

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d, points, connection

I have a series of points in 3D space currently plotted. I would like to connect these together to form a rectangle. The rectangle would need a certain width and height, and somehow should 'wrap' round to the other side of gthe box if it encounters the box boundaries.

My code is below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

x       = [0, 0, 0, 0, 50, 50, 50, 50]
y       = [50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50]
z       = [12.5,37.5,62.5,87.5,25,50,75,0]

fig = pyplot.figure()
ax  = fig.add_subplot(111, projection = '3d')

ax.set_xlim(0,100)
ax.set_ylim(0,100)
ax.set_zlim(0,100)
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')

#ax.view_init(elev=90, azim=90)
ax.scatter(x, y, z, zdir='z', s=20, c='g')

pyplot.show()
```

Does anybody have any ideas? Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

One possible algorithm, is

1. find the vertices of the rectangle
2. reorder vertices to form a rectagle

Here's a possible solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot
from numpy import *
from numpy import linalg
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

x       = array([0, 0, 0, 0, 50, 50, 50, 50])
y       = array([50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50])
z       = array([12.5,37.5,62.5,87.5,25,50,75,0])

data = concatenate((x[:,newaxis],y[:,newaxis],z[:,newaxis]), axis=1)

center = data.mean(axis=0)

distances = empty((0))
for row in data:
    distances = append(distances, linalg.norm(row - center))

vertices = distances.argsort()[-4:]
Vertices_reorder = [vertices[0], vertices[2], vertices[1], vertices[3], vertices[0]]

# plot:
fig = pyplot.figure()
ax  = fig.add_subplot(111, projection = '3d')

ax.set_xlim(0,100)
ax.set_ylim(0,100)
ax.set_zlim(0,100)
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')

#ax.view_init(elev=90, azim=90)
ax.scatter(x, y, z, zdir='z', s=20, c='g')
ax.plot(x[Vertices_reorder], y[Vertices_reorder], z[Vertices_reorder])

fig.savefig("rect.png")
```

Result:

[image]

I'm not sure reordering implemented would work for all situations.